# Getting more result-info after WebClient UploadFileAsync FTP uploads

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, ftp, webclient

After my vb.net code uses WebClient to do an FTP UploadFileAsync upload, this subroutine is called:

```
Sub FtpCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs)
End Sub
```

The upload works, and the subroutine gets called... but what code would I put inside it... to get info like:

```
The name of the source-file that just completed?
The name of the destination-file?
The number of bytes transferred?
An error or success number?
An error or success string?
The time the upload started?
```

What info *IS* available to me... when all I have is SENDER and E variables?

Answer (score 0):

For the source file, when you start the asynchronous process you can specify a user token object and refer to it in the e.userstate object. It's just a simple object so you can put whatever you like in it to keep track of what went out. This is my understanding at least, I have never made use of the e.userstate object.

As for the error or success, whenever you refer to asynchronous completed events, you should always first check if e.error is nothing before referencing any other properties of e. If e.error is nothing and e.cancelled is nothing, the transfer was successful. If e.error isnot nothing then probe e.error to find out the error. Don't refer to e.result if e.error is something because that will throw an exception.

Also, doesn't the sender objct refer to the original object you used to send the file? Do a Ctype conversion and you should be able to get details on what you sent.